# Must $\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}$ be small on certain sets for this convex $f$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f \colon \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be a convex smooth function. Assume that the partial derivative $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ satisfies the following condition:

$$- \lambda \le \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} <0 \qquad \text{ everywhere on }\mathbb{R}^2. $$

So if we think $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ as a function on $\mathbb{R}^2$, it is negative, bounded and because of the convexity we have that is non decreasing along the $x$-direction.

**IDEA**: I would like to say that, when $x$ goes to $-\infty$, the second derivative $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}$ must become "somehow" small. For sure we have that for any $y \in \mathbb{R}$: 
$$
\liminf_{x \rightarrow - \infty}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}(x, y) = 0.
$$
But the limit could not exists...

Let consider now "vertical" segments in $\mathbb{R}^2$ of the following kind:
$$
S_L(x) := \{ (x, y) : -L \le y \le L\} = \{x\} \times [-L, L].
$$

I would like to show the following

**CLAIM**: For every $\epsilon > 0$ and for every $L>0$ there exists $x_{\epsilon, L} \in \mathbb{R}$ such that 
$$
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} < \epsilon \qquad \text{ on   }  \quad S_L(x_{\epsilon, L}).
$$

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counterexample: There exists a smooth convex $g$ on $\mathbb R,$ with $-1 \le g' < 0$ everywhere, and $g''(n) > 1$ for every $n\in \mathbb Z.$ Define $f(x,y) = g(x-y).$ Then $f$ is smooth and convex on $\mathbb R^2.$ We also have, for all $(x,y),$

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y) = g'(x-y) \in [-1,0),\,\,\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}(x,y)=g''(x-y).$$

The first equality shows $f$ is of the form you describe.

Verify that $\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} > 1$ on each line $y=x-n, n \in \mathbb Z.$ Think geometrically to see that if $L>1/2,$ then $\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} > 1$ somewhere in each $S_L(x).$

Comment: Right, thanks!!